# Strange compatibility warning on Google Play Vitals

Tags: android

I have recently noticed a few compatibility warnings on the Google Play vitals section for one of my apps. The problem seems to happen at the setContentView point in a certain activity, however I am not sure what is causing the problem - it looks like it is something with the activity Theme but I cannot be sure. The theme of the activity is the following and is defined in the /res/values/folder.

```
<style name="Theme.MainActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils.<clinit>(ViewUtils.java:44)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:685)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.test.MyActivity.b(MyActivity.java:1641)
    at com.test.MyActivity.f(MyActivity.java:373)
    at com.test.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:345)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at ...
```